# visual basic array sorting from list box

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting, arraylist

Hello im having trouble with my code !
we are asked to organize a list of names from a text.txt file the make them show up into a lits box (got that part down :) ) . then from the list box we are asked to create an array and sort that array (using our own sorting method) and organize the names using a button in assending order and another button organizing the array in decending order. the results from the orders names should appear in another list box .
i have gotten only the last name in the list to show up in the second list box but my code has no errors it just wont order the names properly! Help!!!!!

here is my code :)

```
Public Class FileSort
Dim sr As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText("C:\Users\Inspiron 15\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\assigment4 EL\assigment4 EL\names.txt")

Structure names
Dim c As Integer
Dim fullname As String
End Structure

Dim allNames(99) As names

Private Sub btnName_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnName.Click

 Do While sr.Peek <> -1
    Name = sr.ReadLine
    LstNames.Items.Add(Name & " ")
Loop
sr.Close()

End Sub
Private Sub bubbelsort(ByRef names() As System.String, ByVal c As Integer)
c = 0
names(c) = sr.ReadLine()
c = c * 1
For c = 1 To 99 Step +1 '~~~ Addding (Z to A) to the the Listbox
    lstOrderedNames.Items.Add(Name & "")'
Next

End Sub
Private Sub BtnAssend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnAssend.Click

Dim names(99) As String
Dim c As Integer
c = 0
Dim A As Integer
A = 99
names(c) = sr.ToString
c = c + 1
For c = 1 To 99 Step +1 '~~~ Addding (Z to A) to the the Listbox
    lstOrderedNames.Items.Add(Name & "")
Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnDessend.Click
Dim names(99) As String
Dim c As Integer
c = 0
Dim A As Integer
A = 99
names(c) = sr.ToString
names(A) = sr.ToString
A = A - 1
For A = 99 To 0 Step -1 '~~~ Addding (Z to A) to the the Listbox
    lstOrderedNames.Items.Add(Name & "")
Next
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR3Xu.png)

Comment: you may also want to add some examples of data before and after "treatment"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your problem is the sorting algorithm (if I understand this correctly).

At first we need an array.

```
Dim arr(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1) As String
For i As Integer = 0 To arr.Length - 1
    arr(i) = CStr(ListBox1.Items(i))
Next
```

Next the sorting algorithm. Since you wanted to go with BubbleSort:

```
Private Sub StringBubbleSort(arr As String)
    For i As Integer = 0 To arr.Length - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To arr.Length - 2 - i
            If String.Compare(arr(j), arr(j + 1)) > 0 Then
                Dim temp As String = arr(j)
                arr(j) = arr(i)
                arr(i) = temp
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Then you use this function and copy the array to your second ListBox.

```
StringBubbleSort(arr)
ListBox2.Items.AddRange(arr)
```

String.Compare: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/84787k22(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

you could use linq

```
 ListBox1.Items.Add("Battle")
 ListBox1.Items.Add("Cattle")
 ListBox1.Items.Add("apple")

 ListBox2.DataSource = (From l In ListBox1.Items
                        Select l Order By l Ascending).ToList
```

Comment: Unless that doesn't count as using your own sorting method.

Comment: omg thanks it worked !!! dose that count as creating your own  sort method or dose it fall in the category of using  VB sorting functions ?

Comment: That is definitely a built in sorting method. You could use your own sorting method in the same manner, I'll have to post later on it because it's slightly more involved than I can be at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to log onto here again.